# If two stochastic integrands are equal on some measurable set, will the stochastic integrals be equal on that set?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given a $X$ semi-martingale on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\le\infty},P)$ I am trying to prove:

For any $B\in\mathcal F_\infty$ and processes $a_1,a_2$ such that $\int_t^T a_i\;d\!X$ is well-defined for $i\in\{1,2\}$ it holds:

$$a_1=a_2 \text{ on } B\Longrightarrow P\left(\int_t^T a_1\;d\!X=\int_t^T a_2\;d\!X\middle|B\right)=1$$

#### My proof

Let $(a_i^n)_{n<\infty}$ be a series of simple integrands approximating $a_i$. We can choose them such that $a_1^n=a_2^n$ on $B$ for all $n$. Define $A^n_i=\int_t^T a^n_i\;d\! X$. These integrals of simple integrands are defined path-wise and thus $A_1^n=A_2^n$ on $B$ for each $n$. The integrals of $a_i$ are given by $p\!\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A^n_i$ (limit in probability). Convergence in probability preserves the equivalence on $B$ and the proof it complete.

#### Question

It the proof correct and complete? Is there an easier/correct proof?

Thx

Comment: @ user4514 : As for the other question would you be a little more specific on the meaning that you give to stochastic integrator ? Otherwise regarding your question I would go back to the basic on conditioning by checking you assertion for the expectation of your indicator function multiplied by a undetermined $\sigma(C)$-measurable set. Best regards

Comment: A stochastic integrator is a process, such that the stochastic integral can be defined. I am not specifying it further, as (1) I do not know understand all the differences between possible definitions of stochastic integrals and their allowed integrands (2) I do not think the statement and proof depend to much on these details... I am not sure what you try to say with your second sentence, sorry. Thanks

Comment: @ user4514 : well not really satisfying IMO, can you prove that such object exists and what is stochastic integration ? Anyway what I meant by going back to the basics, was if you want to prove that $E[X|A]=Y$ a.s. then it suffices to show that $E[E[X|A].1_{C}]=E[Y.1_{C}]$ for every sets $C$ in the $\sigma(B)$ Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge (1) I updated the question. Now $X$ is a semi-martingale and I am referring to the (well-developed) theory of stochastic intergrals with semi-martingales. (2) Ok, now I understand what you mean. Still do not see how it helps me. What do you think about my proof?